# Invoke webjob from python

Tags: python, azure, azure-webjobs

Is it possible to invoke a webjob from python?
I currently have a web app and webjob on azure. My webjob is set to triggered/manual and want to run it from python code whenever user does a specific action.
something like this from c#:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://<web appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/<web job name>/run");
request.Method = "POST";
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:password"); 
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+ Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));            
request.ContentLength = 0;
```

I did some research and I saw one post that suggested to use [`azure-sdk-for-python`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python). But I'm not sure if that was any help as far as "triggering the webjob".

Comment: As reference, please refer to the kudu wiki page https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API and to use the webjob REST APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need simply to post a request to the azure, you can use a [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) (`http.client` in Python 3) like this:

```
import base64, httplib
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + base64.b64encode("user:password")}

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("https://<web appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/<web job name>/run")
conn.request("POST", "", "", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
```

If you need some more complicated, you better [investigate](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) the `azure-sdk-for-python` package, but I can't see there anything about the webjobs right now.

This works with postman:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After doing more research i found that webjob can be indeed invoked by post call. it does work using postman but doesnt work with the code similar to the one you posted. Im thinking it could be related to syntax.

Comment: The code above is for Python 2, for the Python 3 it do slightly differ

Comment: the code is fine, i am using python3 and had to modify it with http.client and some other minor changes. It runs without errors just does not do anything (does not start the webjob). I can post the screenshot of postman and my code for better understanding.

Comment: Maybe you need different headers

Comment: I added the screenshot of the postman post call that works maybe you can give me a further help.

Comment: You have one header there one screenshot on the `headers` tab, what is that header's value?

Comment: Try to remove two other my headers, updated the code

Comment: on line: conn.request("POST", "", "", headers) it gets error "socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"

Comment: Similar errors can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/a/185091/187757. It means that your machine can't see the service or doesn't know the IP-address for it.